# C# How i can make this [[string, int],[string, int]]

Tags: c#, arrays

I've two arrays:

1. Array of String
2. Array of Numbners

On output I need an array of arrays of which ever arrays contain `String` or `int`.

Like this:

```
[
  [string, int],
  [string, int],
  [string, int],
]
```

Comment: I want make array which contain another array. Like this list of users with firstname and old [["Alex", 22], ["Ibra", 32], etc]

Comment: I understand what you *want*. You need to provide a minimal effort of doing *something* in order for people here to put in the effort to help you get where you want to be.

Comment: I have two arrays with number and string. and i have js plagin which have func([[string, int], [string, int], [string, int]]).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [LINQ's `Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698.aspx).

```
var strings = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = strings.Zip(ints, (s, i) => new object[] { s, i });
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result.Select(x => "{ " + string.Join(", ", x) + " }")));
```

Results in

```
{ a, 1 }, { b, 2 }, { c, 3 }
```